# Meteor Spacebars {{#if someCondition}} shows data briefly on page refresh

Tags: javascript, meteor, spacebars

I have tried this a couple different ways and they both behave the same way (see below for code). I'm using a spacebars if condition (and tried using a helper as well) to check if the user is logged in, then display login/sign up links if they aren't. If they are, hide them.

What I noticed is that on the initial page load (if they navigate back from a different site), the login/sign up links show quickly before hiding (if the user is still logged in). Is there a way to insure that no elements render in the view if the condition is false? It seems to me that it should check before the view starts rendering, then display the appropriate elements on the page.

Thanks for the help! -Chris

**Solution to the flicker that I was experiencing:**
I was checking against the user, though the view was rendering quicker than the DB query. I added a guard expression (see below) and that seems to take care of the flicker.

```
isUserLoggedOut: function() {
  var user = Meteor.user();

  if(Meteor.user()) {
    return user && false;
  } else{
    return user && true;
  }
}
```

Attempt #1:

```
Template.headerTpl.helpers({
  isUserLoggedIn: function() {
    var user = Meteor.user();

    if(user) {
      return false;
    } else{
      return true;
    }
  }
});

<template name="headerTpl">
  {{#if isUserLoggedIn}}
  <li style="display:none;"><a href="{{pathFor 'userRegistrationFormTpl'}}" id="signup-js">Sign Up</a></li>
  <li><a href="{{pathFor 'userLoginFormTpl'}}" id="login-js">Login</a></li>
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

Attempt #2:

```
Template.headerTpl.helpers({
  isUserLoggedIn: function() {
    var user = Meteor.user();

    if(user) {
      return "hide";
    } else{
      return "show";
    }
  }
});

<template name="headerTpl">
  <li class={{isUserLoggedIn}}><a href="{{pathFor 'userRegistrationFormTpl'}}" id="signup-js">Sign Up</a></li>
  <li class={{isUserLoggedIn}}><a href="{{pathFor 'userLoginFormTpl'}}" id="login-js">Login</a></li>
</template>
```

Attempt #3:

```
{{#if currentUser}}
{{else}}
<li style="display:none;"><a href="{{pathFor 'userRegistrationFormTpl'}}" id="signup-js">Sign Up</a></li>
<li><a href="{{pathFor 'userLoginFormTpl'}}" id="login-js">Login</a></li>
{{/if}}
```

Attempt #4:

```
<template name="headerTpl">
  {{#if isUserLoggedOut}}
    {{> signInLinksTpl}}
  {{/if}}
</template>

<template name="signInLinksTpl">
  <li style="display:none;"><a href="{{pathFor 'userRegistrationFormTpl'}}" id="signup-js">Sign Up</a></li>
  <li><a href="{{pathFor 'userLoginFormTpl'}}" id="login-js">Login</a></li>
</template>

Template.headerTpl.helpers({
  isUserLoggedOut: function() {
    if(Meteor.user()) {
      return false;
    } else{
      return true;
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to subscribe to Meteor.users collection, template will be rendered after Meteor.user() is created, if you won't wait for subscription page will blink because at start there is nothing in Meteor.users collection.

You can use new Meteor functionality on template where you have login field

```
Template.login.onCreated(function () {
  var self = this;

  self.autorun(function () {
    self.subscribe("users");
  });
});
```

And in HTML

```
{{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}}
    <!--content-->
{{else}}
    Give me a second...
{{/if}}
```

Of course you need to create publish named 'users'

Comment: this was it. I tried a few of the above solutions, though wasn't able to make them work as I wanted it to. this solution has done the trick, not to mention leveraging new Meteor tech! Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You can use instead, the `currentUser` helper from accounts package, like this.

```
{{#if currentUser}}
<!-- show content -->
{{else}}
 {{> login }} <!-- render login template -->
{{/if}}
```

**Iron Router Option.**

There is also a solution in the router level, using `Router.onBeforeAction`.

```
// lib/routes.js
// Create the function to check login.
   var requireLogin = function() {
       if (! Meteor.user()) {
          this.render('login');
        } else {
          this.next(); //using this.next the iron router will render the route named on the onBefore
      }
   }

   Router.onBeforeAction(requireLogin, {only: 'theRoute});
```

**UPDATE**

```
Template.headerTpl.helpers({
  isLogged:function(){
   if(Meteor.user()){
      return true;
    }else{
      return false;
    }
  }
})

<template name="headerTpl">
  {{#if isLogged}}
       <h1>Welcome User</h1>
     {{else}}
       <li style="display:none;"><a href="{{pathFor 'userRegistrationFormTpl'}}" id="signup-js">Sign Up</a></li>
       <li><a href="{{pathFor 'userLoginFormTpl'}}" id="login-js">Login</a></li>
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

Comment: Ethaan got it before me. The logic here is if there's a user, show them user content, if not ask them to login.

Comment: Thanks @Ethaan, but your solution is my attempt #3 (see above) which has the same behavior. the links show quickly before they are hidden once the app realizes the user is logged in.

Comment: @Centinel3 did you try the onBefore?

Comment: I'm not rendering a template, I'm showing/hiding links within a template. The links are in the head section of the web app, so the whole template is rendered, then checks to see if the user is logged in before serving up the links. I suppose I could remove the links and put them in their own template and see if that works, though that seems crazy to me. I'll give that a try in a little bit.

Comment: @Centinel3 the `currentUser` helper should work, but check answer update

Comment: Using a separate template has the same behavior. I can see the link briefly before it disappears.

Comment: I tried the new template and still see the links flash before they are hidden. I edited my initial question above with Attepmpt #4 (also implemented the refactor by @thatgibbyguy

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you're thinking about this correctly?

```
isUserLoggedIn: function() { // implies you're checking for the user
    var user = Meteor.user(); // if there's a user this returns true

    if(user) { // you're saying if there's a user ...
        return false; // return false
    } else{ // and if there isn't
    return true; // return true
    }
}
```

Basically you're saying "is the user logged in" and if yes "return false" which is making you double think. Instead, reverse your logic.

```
isUserLoggedOut: function() { // implies you're checking for the user
    var user = Meteor.user(); // if there's a user this returns true

    if(user) { // there is a user
        return false; // so isUserLoggedOut == false
    } else{ // and if there isn't a user
        return true; // isUserLoggedOut == true
    }
}
```

Now your template becomes easy

```
{{#if isUserLoggedOut}}
   {{>loggedOutTemplate}}
{{/if}}
```

Comment: Thanks @thatgibbyguy. Makes sense for sure. I will certainly implement this, though doesn't change the fact that the links still appear briefly before being hidden.

Comment: Ok, well that flash is because your DB hasn't been queried yet. To fix the flash, you can try using a guard https://dweldon.silvrback.com/guards or you can try autorunning as mentioned below. Ironrouter also offers a "waiton" option which is what I generally use to avoid the flash.