# Meteor: How to activate template's helper when a variable is set

Tags: meteor

I have this helper:

```
Template.showScannedData.helpers({
    'lastConnectionNetId': function(){ 
        return Connections.findOne().netId; 
    }
});
```

associated with the following template:

```
<template name="showScannedData">
    {{#if lastConnectionNetId}}}
       my last connection's id: {{lastConnectionNetId}}<br>
    {{/if}}
</template>
```

The issue is that until I don't actually add something to **Connections** collection (which is done within Cordova, by taking some data from an NFC tag and thereafter stored it in MongoDB), I get the following exception:

> Exception in template helper: TypeError: Cannot read property 'netId' of undefined

I understand that the exception is caused by the template activated before the data is available.

Also to "hide" the issue to the user (i.e. not showing an incomplete UI), I added a check in the template

> if lastConnectionNetId

Is this the right way to do it?

**How do I avoid getting the exception as long as the collection is empty?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check my earlier comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29153538/meteor-spacebars-if-somecondition-shows-data-briefly-on-page-refresh/29155408#29155408), you need to wait for data to load.

Also, if you still are not sure if there is any data is in collection you should create helper like:

```
 'lastConnectionNetId': function(){ 
   return Connections.findOne() && Connections.findOne().netId; 
 }
```

More about defensive programming in Meteor is available [here](https://dweldon.silvrback.com/guards)

Answer (score 1):

I your case, findOne returns an object. If no document satisfies the query, the method returns null. That means your object will be empty and netId will be undefined. I would try this:

```
Template.showScannedData.helpers({
    'lastConnection': function(){ 
        return Connections.findOne(); 
    }
});

<template name="showScannedData">
    {{#if lastConnection}}}
       my last connection's id: {{lastConnection.netId}}<br>
    {{/if}}
</template>
```

This could solve your problem.