# Meteor subscribe first fetch empty data then real data

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I published data on the server side, but when I subscribe the data, I first got empty and then real data. How can I subscribe the real data at first?

```
class BlogItem extends Component{
  render(){
      console.log(this.props.posts);
      return(
        this.props.posts.map(post =>{
          return(
            <li className="list-group-item" key={post._id}>
              title:{post.title}
            </li>
          );
        })
      );
  };
}


export default createContainer((props) => {
  Meteor.subscribe('posts');
  return { posts: Posts.find({}).fetch() };
}, BlogItem);
```

publish on server:

```
Meteor.startup(() => {
  Meteor.publish('posts', function() {
   return Posts.find({});
 });
});
```

Comment: How do you publish it on server side

Comment: Updated question. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe it's trying to return something before the subscription is ready? I don't know much about how to use ```subscriptionReady()``` in react, but try giving [this](https://forums.meteor.com/t/react-component-mount-wait-for-subscriptions-ready/13646/2) a read.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28890672/meteor-collection-fetch-returns-empty-array-but-is-subscribed

Comment: Fixed, just ignore the empty array and it is gonna re-render when real data comes.

Comment: This might help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29153538/meteor-spacebars-if-somecondition-shows-data-briefly-on-page-refresh/29155408#29155408

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to make the data get to the client faster. That is how a subscription works. To deal with it, use the subscription handle to test if it is ready and show a loader in the meantime.

```
class BlogItem extends Component {
  render() {
    const {ready, posts} = this.props;
    if (!ready) return (<div>loading...</div>);
    return (
      <ul>
        posts.map(post => (
          <li className="list-group-item" key={post._id}>
            title:{post.title}
          </li>
        ));
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

export default createContainer(() => {
  const handle = Meteor.subscribe('posts');
  return {
      ready: handle.ready(),
      posts: Posts.find({}).fetch(),
  };
}, BlogItem);
```

Comment: Fixed, just ignored the empty array and it is gonna re-render when real data comes.

Comment: You can do that, but imagine you have 25 different return values from your container. Testing each and every one of them whether they are emptz or `undefined` would be very tedious. So use the `subscription-handle`, that is what it's for.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for subscription to complete.

Initially you're getting empty data because your data is not ready.

Wait till your data is ready then pass data, meanwhile show loading page

```
export default createContainer((props) => {
  const handle = Meteor.subscribe('posts');
  if (handle.ready()) {
   return { posts: Posts.find({}).fetch() };
  } else {
    return { loadingData: true, posts: [] }
 }
}, BlogItem);
```

Comment: Fixed, just ignored the empty array and it is gonna re-render when real data comes.