# Cannot get rif of user registration using Meteor and React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

I'm new to Meteor and I'm studying it. Actually I'm creating a User login, Signup page with a private control panel for each registered user.

I'm able to Signup and Login correctly but I I have two different issues:

1. On create user I can not save information to the profile object and it looks like the `onCreateUser` method is not fired at all.
2. When the user log in I get user information in the Control Panel page, but if I refresh the page I do not receive those information anymore even if the user is still logged in.

Here is the code.

**/imports/api/users.js**:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Accounts } from 'meteor/accounts-base';

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.publish('userData', () => {
    return Meteor.users.find({ _id: Meteor.userId() }, {
      fields: { profile: 1 }
    });
  });
}

Accounts.onCreateUser((options, user) => {
  user.profile = options.profile || {};
  user.profile.accountType = options.accountType;

  return user;
});
```

**/imports/ui/Signup.js**:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Accounts } from 'meteor/accounts-base';
import Joi from 'joi';
import validation from 'react-validation-mixin';
import strategy from 'joi-validation-strategy';
import classnames from 'classnames';

import history from '../../utils/history';

class Signup extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.validatorTypes = {
      accountType: Joi.string().required().label('Account type'),
      email: Joi.string().email().label('Email'),
      password: Joi.string().required().min(6).label('Password'),
      confirmPassword: Joi.string().required().min(6).valid(Joi.ref('password')).label('Confirm password').options({
        language: {
          any: {
            allowOnly: '!!Passwords do not match'
          }
        }
      })
    };

    this.getValidatorData = this.getValidatorData.bind(this);
    this.renderHelpText = this.renderHelpText.bind(this);
    this.getClasses = this.getClasses.bind(this);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      serverError: ''
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    if (Meteor.userId()) {
      history.replace('/');
    }
  }

  getValidatorData() {
    return {
      accountType: this.refs.accountType.value,
      email: this.refs.email.value,
      password: this.refs.password.value,
      confirmPassword: this.refs.confirmPassword.value
    };
  }

  renderHelpText(message) {
    return (
      <span className='validation-error-message'>{message}</span>
    );
  }

  getClasses(field) {
    return classnames({
      'form-group': true,
      'has-error': !this.props.isValid(field)
    });
  }

  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const onValidate = error => {
      if (!error) {
        let accountType = this.refs.accountType.value;
        let email = this.refs.email.value.trim();
        let password = this.refs.password.value.trim();
        let confirmPassword = this.refs.confirmPassword.value.trim();

        Accounts.createUser({ email, password, accountType }, (err) => {
          if (err) {
            this.setState({
              serverError: err.reason
            });
          } else {
            this.setState({
              serverError: ''
            });
            history.replace('/account');
          }
        });
      }
    };

    this.props.validate(onValidate);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="form-container">
        <h3>Create Account</h3>
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          <div className={this.getClasses('accountType')}>
            <select
              className="form-control"
              name="accountType"
              ref="accountType"
              placeholder="Account type"
              onChange={this.props.handleValidation('accountType')}
            >
              <option value="">Select account type</option>
              <option value="student">Sudent</option>
              <option value="teacher">Teacher</option>
              <option value="guest">Guest</option>
            </select>
            {this.renderHelpText(this.props.getValidationMessages('accountType')[0])}
          </div>
          <div className={this.getClasses('email')}>
            <input
              className="form-control"
              type="text"
              name="email"
              ref="email"
              placeholder="email address"
              onChange={this.props.handleValidation('email')}
            />
            {this.renderHelpText(this.props.getValidationMessages('email')[0])}
          </div>
          <div className={this.getClasses('password')}>
            <input
              className="form-control"
              type="password"
              name="password"
              ref="password"
              placeholder="password"
              onChange={this.props.handleValidation('password')}
            />
            {this.renderHelpText(this.props.getValidationMessages('password')[0])}
          </div>
          <div className={this.getClasses('confirmPassword')}>
            <input
              className="form-control"
              type="password"
              name="confirmPassword"
              ref="confirmPassword"
              placeholder="confirm password"
              onBlur={this.props.handleValidation('confirmPassword')}
            />
            {this.renderHelpText(this.props.getValidationMessages('confirmPassword')[0])}
          </div>
          <button className="btn btn-dark" type="submit">Create</button>
        </form>
        <div className="meta">
          <p>Already have an account? <Link to="/login">Login</Link></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
};

export default validation(strategy)(Signup);
```

What I expect is when I create a new use the method in `users.js` called `Accounts.onCreateUser` get fired and the `accountType` information is added to profile. It doesn't happen.

I also expect to always retrieve the current logged in user information in the control panel. Here is the control panel component:

**/imports/ui/Account.js**:

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';

import history from '../../utils/history';

```
class Account extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    Meteor.subscribe('userData');

    this.state = {
      user: {}
    }
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    if (!Meteor.userId()) {
      history.replace('/login');
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(Meteor.userId()); // I can always get this value
    const user = Meteor.users.find({ _id: Meteor.userId() }, {
      fields: { profile: 1 }
    }).fetch();
    console.log(user); // On refresh it is an empty array [].

    this.setState({ user });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>Hello Account</div>
    );
  }
};

export default Account;
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things wrong with your code but they can easily be fixed.

1. `Accounts.onCreateUser` is a server only function. Insert a `console.log` into 
   the function just to make sure it is called. If not, make sure that you 
   `import '/imports/api/users.js'` in your `main.js`.
2. `Accounts.createUser` accepts only 4 keys in the options object: `username`, `email`, `password` and `profile` (see [docs](https://docs.meteor.com/api/passwords.html#Accounts-createUser)). That is why `accountType` is not passed to `onCreateUser`. Do `Accounts.createUser({ email, password, profile: { accountType } }, ...)`. Then in `onCreateUser` you find the `accountType` under `options.profile.accountType`.
3. To subscribe to data you should use meteors `createContainer` component. See [the guide](https://guide.meteor.com/react.html#data). That will solve the problem that your data is not yet available when the component mounts and will rerender it when the data is ready.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I will test it out! Cheers

Comment: Well, I forgot to import my `users.js` to `main.js` as you mentioned. Now the profile is correctly saving my data. I do not understand very well your 3rd point. In all guides I followed on Udemy that `createContainer` component has never been mentioned. Why I cannot just query for user data from `componentDidMount`? Can you please write a more detailed example on how to get user data using your approach? Following that guide I'm not able to achieve it. Cheers.

Comment: look at my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44299378/meteor-subscribe-first-fetch-empty-data-then-real-data/44300276#44300276

Comment: `componentDidMount` will only run once, `createContainer` will rerun when the data is ready.